# Writing CSV file with arabic unicode in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, unicode, arabic

I am trying to write a csv file that contains a number of lists.  Within some of the lists, there is unicode that contains arabic.  For example:

```
list1 = ['No data'], list2 = ['data1', 'data2, '\\u...', '\\u...']
```

The unicode also contains an extra backslash.  How would I create a csv, or change my code, to convert the unicode to arabic characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encode/decode the char by using the following function :

```
your_string.encode("utf-8").decode('unicode-escape')
```

for example:

```
test = "test \\u0643\\uFEBD"
print(test.encode("utf-8").decode('unicode-escape')) => test كﺽ
```

***EDIT 1:***
to convert all your arrays you can either loop thru all the elements and convert them 1 by 1 or use **map** function like :

```
def f(string):
    return string.encode("utf-8").decode('unicode-escape')

for sublist in main_list:
    sublist = list(map(f, sublist))
```

Comment: My issue dealt more with iterating this unicode data over lists.  I have a main list which contain smaller lists, where the unicode data is stored.  How would I be able to encode/decode this information nested in the lists?

Comment: I'm still getting the error I had with my original code, which is     'list' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: This is because you are not running the "encode" function on a string, but on array. Can you provide more code in your question?